# What can I say about a (non-square) matrix that preserves norm?

Tags: linear-algebra

If a matrix is square and preserves norm, then it is orthogonal, and we know many things about it, e.g. that the columns form an ONB, as do the rows.

Can we say something similar for a non-square matrix that preserves the norm (i.e. a linear isometry between finite dimensional vector spaces)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say that the matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ has more rows than columns (i.e. $m>n$) and that the columns of the matrix still form an orthonormal basis of a $n$-dimensional **subspace** of $\mathbb R^m$.